# How to keep a opened port open after reboot on Linux?

Tags: linux, port, reboot

I have used
`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp`
to open a port for node server app, and used pm2 to ensure that node app will automatically start after reboot, however the port setting will be reset.

I am new to Linux, can anyone tell me how to do or some keywords for studying further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `--permanent` after your command.

I'm not sure if you did, but make sure you run `firewall-cmd --reload` to relaunch the firewall with the new settings.

To find out more about `firewall-cmd`, you can run `man firewall-cmd` to view the documentation.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!